# ntlmv2-auth fails in Session key negotiation

Tags: java, liferay, jboss-4.2.x, jcifs, ntlmv2

We are trying to port our jboss j2ee application from ntlm-auth to ntlmv2-auth.

AppServer: JBoss v. 4.5.2, java6, jcifs 1.3.17, ntlmv2-auth 1.0.4
AD-server: Windows Server 2003 - with a computer account in the AD created acc. to specifications from Liferay. NTLMv2 is off course enabled on the server; 'Send NTLMv2 response only\refuse LM and NTLM'

Authentication fails with a NtlmLogonException: Session key negotiation failed

From the AD-servers Event viewer logon/logoff traces off the computer account can be seen.

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR org.ntlmv2.filter.NtlmFilter - NTLM authentication failed:
org.ntlmv2.liferay.NtlmLogonException: Session key negotiation failed
org.ntlmv2.liferay.NtlmLogonException: Session key negotiation failed
    at org.ntlmv2.liferay.NetlogonConnection.connect(NetlogonConnection.java:172)
    at org.ntlmv2.liferay.Netlogon.logon(Netlogon.java:50)
    at org.ntlmv2.liferay.NtlmManager.authenticate(NtlmManager.java:66)
    at org.ntlmv2.filter.NtlmFilter.doFilter(NtlmFilter.java:236)
```

Could anyone please enlighten me on this one?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Cartsen I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After reading carefully the [documentation from Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/fr/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/NTLMv2+SSO+Configuration), it turns out I was using a Person account instead of a **Computer account** in the ntlm-account configuration of ntlmv2-auth.